# submit button doesn't post data while using jquery.validation.js

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, form-submit, unobtrusive-validation, remote-validation

for using Remote validation , C# Asp .net core, I add this two libraries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/3.2.11/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

but these **STOP** submitting button and posting data.
My Model prop:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Captions))]
[Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Titles))]
[Remote("ValidateUsername", "SignUp")]
[RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z_]*$", ErrorMessageResourceName = "Wrong_Format", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Captions))]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

and in controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(SignUpViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(model);
        var user = _mapper.Map<User>(model);
        var addUserResult = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (addUserResult.Succeeded)
        {
            var addRoleResult = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, RoleNames.Client);
            if (addRoleResult.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = GenerateValidationCode();
                bool sendSmsResult = _sendSms.SendSignUpValidationCode(model.PhoneNumber);
                if (sendSmsResult) return RedirectToAction("ValidationCode");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }


//---Remote Action----
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateUsername(string username)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
            if (user != null) return Json(data: Messages.Username_Already_Taken);
            return Json(data: true);
        }
```

In Razor page I have:

```
<form method="post" id="signup" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="SignUp">
        <div class="text-right mt-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Username)
            <input type="text" id="username" asp-for="Username" class="form-control form-log-in">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(r => r.Username, "", new {@class = "error"})
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn see-more-btn px-3 py-1 text-dark text-center text-decoration-none w-100 d-block">ثبت نام</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

***Remote validation works well, and submitting happens while libraries are commented.***

Comment: You need to put `query.validate.js` before `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js`.Do you have any error in your Console?

Comment: yeah!!I used an other remote validator for another field which action wasn't implemented,, it prevents  posting data. thank u :)